# how i can selected item of listBox after enter the index in textBox c#

Tags: c#, indexing, textbox, listbox, selectedindex

```
        int index;
        index = int.Parse(txtIndex.Text);
        lstList.SelectedIndex = index;  [enter image description here][1]
```

when i enter "2" he select the third name in listBox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
lstList.SetSelected(index, true);
```

NOTE: ListBox items are zero index based so be sure that you have the correct input